# Powershell XmlWriterSettings ident Chars as tabs

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a powershell script that edits and writers an XML file but is not keeping the tabbing.

```
[xml]$xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\pom.xml)
$xml.project.parent.version = "1.1.31"

$xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true
$settings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$settings.Indent = $true
$settings.IndentChars = "\t"
$settings.NewLineChars ="`r`n"

$writerXML = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create("C:\project\pom.xml", $settings)
$xml.Save($writerXML)
$writerXML.Dispose()
```

I would expect the `$settings.IndentChars = "\t"` to correctly set the tabbing but instead of getting a tab character I get this

```
\t\t<version>1.1.31</version>
```

Comment: You need to use `t for tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell language, the tab character is represented by the character sequence `t. The sequence is case-sensitive and should be enclosed in double quotes. The following will suffice.

```
$settings.IndentChars = "`t"
```

See [About Special Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-6) for more information on accepted special character sequences.